# String unwanted character in c

Tags: arrays, c, string, char, concatenation

I am trying to add integers to a string. When I debug my code everything works perfectly fine, but when i run it normally two unwanted characters are being printed at the beginning of the string. How do I avoid this?

```
    int number_of_ints = 5;
    char s[number_of_ints*2];
    char suffix[4];
    for(int i = 1; i <= number_of_ints; i++){
        snprintf(suffix, number_of_ints, "%d*", i);
        strncat(s, suffix, 2);
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
```

This is the output when building and running the code normally.

```
`û1*
`û1*2*
`û1*2*3*
`û1*2*3*4*
`û1*2*3*4*5*
```

Comment: You must initialize `s`. You must allocate room for the null terminator.

Comment: The length parameter for your `snprintf` does not make sense. `suffix` can only hold strings of length 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) in C are a sequence of nonzero bytes followed by a terminating byte with a value of zero (the null-terminating byte, `'\0'`).

You must size your buffer to have an additional space, to guarantee room for this null-terminating byte.

You must additionally make sure the contents of the buffer contain a valid string. You can do this by setting the first element of the buffer to the null-terminating byte, creating a zero-length string.

Failing to initialize the contents of your buffer means it will contain *indeterminate values*, and passing such a buffer to a function expecting a valid [string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) will invoke [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

The second argument to [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) should be, at most, the size of the destination buffer.

Finally, consider using [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) when applicable, as it is the appropriate type for dealing with memory sizes (e.g., sizing [variable-length arrays](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays); the [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) operator resolves to this type; [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) expects this type as its second argument).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    size_t number_of_ints = 5;
    char s[number_of_ints * 2 + 1];
    char suffix[4];

    s[0] = '\0';

    for (size_t i = 1; i <= number_of_ints; i++) {
        snprintf(suffix, sizeof suffix, "%zu*", i);
        strncat(s, suffix, 2);
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with initialization and size of your buffers.

- The size of your buffer is too short by 1 byte that is needed for 0-termination. Adding the last number causes buffer overrun and undefined behaviour.
- In addition the calculated size is only sufficient as long as `number_of_ints<10` because it only allows for single digit numbers.
- That buffer is not initialized and us very likely not holding an empty string. Accessing it (via `strcat` etc.) invokes undefined behaviour.
- The size you provide to `snprintf` is not related to the size of the buffer.

You should apply these changes:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number_of_ints = 5;
    char s[number_of_ints*2+1];
    char suffix[4];
    s[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_ints; i++)
    {
        snprintf(suffix, sizeof(suffix), "%d*", i);
        strncat(s, suffix, 2);
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
}
```

Comment: `number_of_ints` is not a [*constant*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant) (different from `const`), thus `s` is actually a [VLA](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays), and VLAs cannot be initialized. This [code](https://godbolt.org/z/4E6ejWMqn) will not (should not) compile, even if you fix the syntax error.

Comment: @Oka You're right. Thanks for pointing it out.